# Как в Sublime Text настроить выполнение Python-программы через build system(с автосохранением файла перед запуском)?

Tags: python, sublime-text

Через бинды клавиатуры смог заставить с помощью SublimeREPL выполнять питоновский файл(т.к. нужен imput), но после каждой правки необходимо сохранять файл. Как назначить выполнение через подменю New build system?